# Mix SLF4J with Log4J

Tags: java, log4j, logging, slf4j

I've got a logger implementing the SLF4J interface and a class `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` implementing `org.slf4j.spi.LoggerFactoryBinder` on the classpath, because it is in the same jar as other required dependencies.

Now I want to use the Log4J-Logger in a project using the `Log4J` interface only, but relying on other libs which use SLF4J. Therefore I will have to throw a `SLF4J-LOG4J-Bridge` into the classpath.

I'm wondering if my `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` will interfere with the `SLF4J-LOG4J-Bridge`. Must I remove my `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` to get the `LOG4J-Logger` working. Or asked differently: Does the `SLF4J-LOG4J-Bridge` also implement `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder` is an class and not an interface.

If you go to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.4, download and open the jar you will see that it doesn't contain `StaticLoggerBinder` class.

Comment: Thanks, I never said org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder is an interface. Is the brigde usage got a higher priority than implementing a StaticLoggerBinder?

Comment: I understood it from _Does the SLF4J-LOG4J-Bridge also implement org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder?_ The SLF4J-LOG4J-Bridge doesn't contain `StaticLoggerBinder` so this class will not interfere interfere.